# How can games possibly detect a macro?

Tags: macros, bots, pyautogui

So I have been playing this 2D online RPG game. It's really retro-styled,  kinda old, but really well managed. I decided to create a bot to grind in game, the farming mechanics is simple.

I don't know how to describe it very well, sorry. So a bar will appear and there will be an object running through the bar, and another object wilL spawn in random position in the bar and you have to press a key when it's aligned. I think you might get the idea.

So I scripted the bot with python using pyautogui. After a couple hours of using it, I was caught by one of the moderator and accused of using macro. I had no idea how they found it out, it was suprising given that it's just a retro game and they had such great monitor over the game.

I really need to know how they did it so I can create a better bot. The only thing I think possible is that they are measuring every click rate(by that, i mean like the very small delay between clicking and releasing the key) and returns an alert whenever the same click rate are being repeated for a certain amount if time, I could be wrong I don't know much about API or whatever can possibly be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways.

The most obvious is probably this:  player score and level completion times, or whatever metric measures success, dramatically increased in short period. It could simply be the bot plays too well. I mean, I wrote a Minesweeper bot to beat a level in under 1 second. It's pretty obvious a human couldn't do that. My bot just beat out other bots for the best time.

Other things:  tools like `pyautogui` tend to generate a limited set of input events. It may generate a "click" but fail to generate the "move" events that would move the mouse to that location. Or, the mouse movements from point A to point B are perfectly straight, without the variation a human moving a mouse would have.

Then, timing, as you suspect. A rapid click rate without stopped looks like a bot.  Could be clicks/second or a consistency of timing.

In general, not enough mistakes (or too many, depending on the game. Clicking on every point of the screen to find something is a giveaway), too fast, too rigid.

You are busted at this point, so for that particular game you should probably give up.